# I'm designing a flow rate based traffic controller on raspberry pi, it runs in an infinite loop

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm designing a flow rate based traffic controller on raspberry pi using buttons as traffic simulators. the problem i'm facing is that the maximum value gets selected at first and there can be no increments possible to that value and the code runs in an infinite loop.

For ex if i press the button at road 1 on the circuit; it will take it as the maximum value as the count of other three roads viz. road two, road three, road 4 are zero and the loop continues with only the traffic lights at road 1 going green and red and the counts of the button presses at the other three streets are not considered at all.
Please help me with the logic as i'm a newbie with python.
Here's my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
count = 0
count2 = 0
count3 = 0
count4 = 0
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN)
#red1
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
#yellow1
GPIO.setup(27,GPIO.OUT)
#green1
GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.OUT)
#RT1
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)
#red2
GPIO.setup(14,GPIO.OUT)
#yellow2
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.OUT)
#green2
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
#RT2
GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.OUT)
#red3
GPIO.setup(10,GPIO.OUT)
#yellow3
GPIO.setup(9,GPIO.OUT)
#green3
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
#RT3
GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)
#red4
GPIO.setup(2,GPIO.OUT)
#yellow4
GPIO.setup(3,GPIO.OUT)
#green4
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)
#RT4
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.OUT)


while True: 
    if (GPIO.input(20) == False):
        count=count+1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(count)
    if (GPIO.input(21) == False):
        count2=count2+1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(count2)
    if (GPIO.input(19) == False):
        count3=count3+1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(count3)
    if (GPIO.input(25) == False):
        count4=count4+1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(count4)
    if count > count2 :
        if count > count3:
            if count > count4:
                print ("Traffic on road 1 highest")
                #go go go...RT1+Str1
                GPIO.output(17,False)
                GPIO.output(27,False)
                GPIO.output(22,True)
                GPIO.output(12,True)
                GPIO.output(14,True)
                GPIO.output(15,False)
                GPIO.output(18,False)
                GPIO.output(16,False)
                GPIO.output(10,True)
                GPIO.output(9,False)
                GPIO.output(11,False)
                GPIO.output(24,False)
                GPIO.output(2,True)
                GPIO.output(3,False)
                GPIO.output(13,False)
                GPIO.output(23,False)
                time.sleep(10)
                #RT1 blinks
                GPIO.output(12,False)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(12,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(12,False)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(12,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(12,False)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(27,True) #yellow
                time.sleep(3)
                GPIO.output(27,False)
                GPIO.output(17,True)
                time.sleep(1) #red

    elif count2 > count:
        if count2 > count3:
            if count2 > count4:
                print ("Traffic on road 2 highest")
                GPIO.output(11,False)
                GPIO.output(10,True)
                GPIO.output(18,True)
                GPIO.output(16,True)
                GPIO.output(14,False)
                GPIO.output(24,False)
                GPIO.output(17,True)
                GPIO.output(27,False)
                GPIO.output(22,False)
                GPIO.output(12,False)
                GPIO.output(15,False)
                GPIO.output(9,False)
                GPIO.output(11,False)
                GPIO.output(24,False)
                GPIO.output(2,True)
                GPIO.output(3,False)
                GPIO.output(13,False)
                GPIO.output(23,False)
                time.sleep(10)
                #RT2 blinks
                GPIO.output(16,False)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(16,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(16,False)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(16,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(16,False)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(15,True)
                time.sleep(3)
                GPIO.output(15,False) #yellow
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(14,True) #red
                time.sleep(1)

    elif count3 > count:
        if count3 > count2:
            if count3 > count4:
                print ("Traffic on road 3 highest")
                GPIO.output(11,False)
                GPIO.output(10,False)
                GPIO.output(18,False)
                GPIO.output(16,False)
                GPIO.output(14,True)
                GPIO.output(24,False)
                GPIO.output(17,True)
                GPIO.output(27,False)
                GPIO.output(22,False)
                GPIO.output(12,False)
                GPIO.output(15,False)
                GPIO.output(9,False)
                GPIO.output(11,True)
                GPIO.output(24,True)
                GPIO.output(2,True)
                GPIO.output(3,False)
                GPIO.output(13,False)
                GPIO.output(23,False)
                time.sleep(10)
                #RT3 blinks
                GPIO.output(24,False)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(24,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(24,False)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(24,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(24,False)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(9,True)
                time.sleep(3)
                GPIO.output(9,False) #yellow
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(10,True) #red
                time.sleep(1)
    elif count4 > count:
        if count4 > count2:
            if count4 > count3:
                print ("Traffic on road 4 highest")
                GPIO.output(11,False)
                GPIO.output(10,True)
                GPIO.output(18,False)
                GPIO.output(16,False)
                GPIO.output(14,True)
                GPIO.output(24,False)
                GPIO.output(17,True)
                GPIO.output(27,False)
                GPIO.output(22,False)
                GPIO.output(12,False)
                GPIO.output(15,False)
                GPIO.output(9,False)
                GPIO.output(11,False)
                GPIO.output(24,False)
                GPIO.output(2,False)
                GPIO.output(3,False)

                GPIO.output(13,True)
                GPIO.output(23,True)
                time.sleep(10)
                #RT2 blinks
                GPIO.output(23,False)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(23,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(23,False)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(23,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(23,False)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(3,True)
                time.sleep(3)
                GPIO.output(3,False) #yellow
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(2,True) #red
                time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting confused by all the layered if statements. You can use the keyword "and" in between them to combine all the ifs into one. Still, I didn't see any fault that would cause your problem. Also, if you want to change variables that are declared outside a loop, you will need to use a `global` statement. Here's some corrected code:

```
#import statements
count1 = 0
count2 = 0
count3 = 0
count4 = 0
#declare gpio pins
while True:
    global count1
    global count2
    global count3
    global count4
    #logic
```

However, it is advised to not use global variables in your code. So, if you find another solution, use it instead.